# Excel VBA Find and return results matching multiple criteria

Tags: vba, excel, matrix, formula

So i use this function in order to find all the times that a word appear:

Ex:

```
=BusquedaSimple(Sheet1!B1:B6; "*"&ESPACIOS(B1)&"*"; 1)

`sheet1`
    A       B       C
1 Basic    Case1   Return1
2 Basic6   Case1   Return2
3 Basic    Case1   Return3
4 Basic2   Case2   Return4
5 Basic    Case2   Return5
6 Basic5   Case3   Return6

`sheet2`
    A       B       C
1 Basic    Case1    =FUNCTION
2 Basic    Case2    =FUNCTION
3 Basic2   Case3    =FUNCTION
```

VBA Function:

```
Function BusquedaSimple(rng As Range, val As String, col As Long)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long, v, s
Dim r As Long

r = rng.Cells.count
v = Application.Match(val, rng, 0)
s = ""
Do While Not IsError(v)
    s = s & IIf(s <> "", Chr(10), "") & rng.Cells(v).Offset(0, col - 1).Value & ":" & rng.Cells(v).Offset(0, 0).Value
    r = r - v
    Set rng = rng.Offset(v, 0).Resize(r, 1)
    v = Application.Match(val, rng, 0)
Loop
BusquedaSimple = s
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Function
```

This works fine, but know, i need to match two criterias, for example:

```
=BusquedaSimple((Sheet1!B1:B6; "*"&ESPACIOS(B1)&"*"); (Sheet1!A1:A6; "*"&ESPACIOS(A1)&"*"); 1)
```

So, i need to find all the times that have a string like "*Case1*" appear, BUT, i need to be sure that the line also have a string like "*Basic*", and store in one cell (Not the count) but each complete string finded.

How can i achive this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what you want to do, but I think you can achieve whatever you want a lot easier. when using VBA you don't need to stick with worksheet functions. I suggest to use this function to count the number of occurrences of two given strings. You can then probably develop this more to get what you exactly want:

```
Function CountOccurrences(rng As Range, str1 As String, str2 As String) As Integer
    Dim cell As Range
   Dim count As Integer
   Dim WS As Worksheet

   Set WS = ActiveSheet
   count = 0

   For Each cell In rag
       If InStr(str1, cell.Value) > 0 And InStr(str2, cell.Value) > 0 Then
           count = count + 1
       End If
   Next cell

   CountOccurrences = count
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the thing is i must record in one cell all the matches, not the count.

Comment: if you could give us an example of the input and the output it will be a lot easier to figure out what exactly you want to do

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use the native formula, like COUNTIFS, or an array as below?

`=SUM(--(LEFT(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$6,5)="Basic")*--(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$6="Case1"))+SUM(--(LEFT(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$6,5)="Basic")*--(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$6="Case1"))`